# Loading compressed baboon interaction data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, byte, gzip

I am interested in reading the observational data and wearable sensor data available [here](http://www.sociopatterns.org/datasets/baboons-interactions/) into Python. Specifically, I would like to get them into Pandas dataframes, but even getting them into a more familiar form would effectively answer the question.

Both files are `*.txt.gz` files. I have tried to read them like this:

```py
import gzip

with gzip.open('../data/OBS_data.txt.gz', 'rb') as f:
    file_content=f.read()

print(file_content)
```

But it is clear from printing the file contents that it is in some sort of encoding. I tried converting it a `utf-8` string unsuccesfully with

```py
file_content.decode("utf-8")
```

But this gives the error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [15], line 4
      1 with gzip.open('../data/OBS_data.txt.gz', 'r') as f:
      2     file_content=f.read()
----> 4 print(file_content.decode("utf-8"))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I also tried using Pandas directly:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('../data/OBS_data.txt.gz', compression='gzip')
```

But that gives a similar error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [17], line 1
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv('../data/OBS_data.txt.gz', compression='gzip')

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:586, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    571 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    572     dialect,
    573     delimiter,
   (...)
    582     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
    583 )
    584 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 586 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:482, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    479 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    481 # Create the parser.
--> 482 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    484 if chunksize or iterator:
    485     return parser

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:811, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    808 if "has_index_names" in kwds:
    809     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
--> 811 self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:1040, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, engine)
   1036     raise ValueError(
   1037         f"Unknown engine: {engine} (valid options are {mapping.keys()})"
   1038     )
   1039 # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1040 return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py:69, in CParserWrapper.__init__(self, src, **kwds)
     67 kwds["dtype"] = ensure_dtype_objs(kwds.get("dtype", None))
     68 try:
---> 69     self._reader = parsers.TextReader(self.handles.handle, **kwds)
     70 except Exception:
     71     self.handles.close()

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:642, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:1917, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

So I may have misunderstood the encoding.

How do I load this data?

---

Strangely, this works

```py
df2 = pd.read_csv('http://www.sociopatterns.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/RFID_data.txt.gz', sep='\t')
print(df2.head())
```

```py
            t        i         j          DateTime
0  1560396500  ARIELLE      FANA  13/06/2019 05:28
1  1560396500  ARIELLE  VIOLETTE  13/06/2019 05:28
2  1560396520     FANA    HARLEM  13/06/2019 05:28
3  1560396540   FELIPE    ANGELE  13/06/2019 05:29
4  1560396540  ARIELLE      FANA  13/06/2019 05:29
```

but this doesn't

```py
df = pd.read_csv('http://www.sociopatterns.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/OBS_data.txt.gz', sep='\t')
print(df.head())
```

```py
Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug 10 2022, 11:40:04) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> df = pd.read_csv('http://www.sociopatterns.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/OBS_data.txt.gz', sep='\t')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 482, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 811, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1040, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py", line 69, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(self.handles.handle, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 642, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1917, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

My version of `pandas` is `1.3.5`, and here is my OS (pretty fresh install; last week):

```bash
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Reinstalling `pandas` didn't work. I tried removing all 3rd party Python packages, then reinstalling pandas using `pip` and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-complicating things, `pandas.read_csv` will read zipped files without having to unzip them.~

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://www.sociopatterns.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/OBS_data.txt.gz', sep='\t')
print(df.head())

df2 = pd.read_csv('http://www.sociopatterns.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/RFID_data.txt.gz', sep='\t')
print(df2.head())
```

Output:

```
            t        i         j          DateTime
0  1560396500  ARIELLE      FANA  13/06/2019 05:28
1  1560396500  ARIELLE  VIOLETTE  13/06/2019 05:28
2  1560396520     FANA    HARLEM  13/06/2019 05:28
3  1560396540   FELIPE    ANGELE  13/06/2019 05:29
4  1560396540  ARIELLE      FANA  13/06/2019 05:29

           DateTime  Actor Recipient   Behavior Category  Duration Point
0  13/06/2019 09:35  EWINE       NaN  Invisible    Other        34    NO
1  13/06/2019 09:35  EWINE       NaN      Other    Other        21    NO
2  13/06/2019 09:35  EWINE       NaN  Invisible    Other        42    NO
3  13/06/2019 09:36  EWINE       NaN      Other    Other         2    NO
4  13/06/2019 09:36  EWINE       NaN  Invisible    Other        30    NO
```

---

If downloaded already:

```
df = pd.read_csv('../data/OBS_data.txt.gz', sep='\t')
```

Comment: Your code also failed to run in my environment with the same error, which immediately led me to checking in a different environment. The problem appears to be something wrong with my Jupyter notebook, but that is a separate problem. I will accept your answer after the 5 minute requirement is satisfied.

Comment: Hang on, your code for `df2` worked in the Jupyter notebook, but not the code for `df1`. And your code for `df1` did not work in an interactive session (Python 3.10.6). The `df1` code did not work in my Jupyter notebook either. Confusing.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you~ https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkEAM.png - This is also `pandas 1.3.5` and `python 3.10.6`~

Comment: That was on my mac, but I tested in linux as well, `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`, `pandas 1.3.5`, `python 3.10.6` worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for checking that. There must be something wrong with my system.

Comment: Upgraded my Ubuntu as well, still worked. So yeah, definitely something specific to your system. I'd recommend using `conda` ... but that's an opinion loaded recommendation haha